# Eloquent: Composite WhereIn condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Is there a clean way to do a composite `WHERE ... IN ()` condition with Eloquent/laravel.

The query result would be :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (relation_type, relation_id) IN (('App\\Model', 1),('App\\Model', 3))
```

As you can see, that would be helpful for a single query fetch of an entity with polymorphic relation linked to 5 other models.

My current solution would be pure `MySQL`:

```php
//Example :array of array with Model name & id
$couples = [
    ['relation_type' => 'App\\Model', 'relation_id' => 1],
    ['relation_type' => 'App\\ModelTwo', 'relation_id' => 2],
    ['relation_type' => 'App\\ModelThree', 'relation_id' => 5],
    ['relation_type' => 'App\\ModelTwo', 'relation_id' => 20],
    //...
    ['relation_type' => 'App\\Model', 'relation_id' => 999],
];
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ('relation_type', 'relation_id') IN (("
        .implode('),(', array_map(function ($entry) {
            return "'".$entry['relation_type']."',".$entry['relation_id']; //I know , in relation_type the '\' needs to be escaped. 
        }, $couples))
        ."))";
$results = \DB::select($query);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://zaengle.com/blog/using-wherehas-in-laravel-polymorphic-relations

Comment: That did work, and requires that i split the array into multiple ones (one per related model) but it seem to be way more slow. i have 5 related models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are able to put in `DB::raw` in both column and value, this will solve the problem of getting the SQL query correct, i tested the following on `MySql 5.7` and it works. Db::raw just adds raw strings to the query, can be dangerous with injections.

```
->whereIn(DB::raw('(relation_type, relation_id)'), [DB::raw("('App\\Model', '2')")])
```

Now we just need to convert your array into that structure, my approach was a array_map `foreach` can also do the trick.

```
$couples = array_map(function ($item) {
    $type = $item['relation_type'];
    $id = $item['relation_id'];

    return DB::raw("('$type', '$id')");
}, $couples);
```

Then call it with a simple `Laravel` query and you should be good to go.

```
$models = Model::whereIn(DB::raw('(relation_type, relation_id)'), $couples)->get()
```